# How to get records with single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table with three columns id, follower_id, following_id  and I have only one id that is **101** or **105** now I want that records suppose `user1` follow to `user2` and `user2` follow to `user1` **in one query**.

table structure

```
----------------------------------
|id | follower_id | following_id |
----------------------------------
|1  |   101       | 105          |
|2  |   105       | 102          |
|3  |   105       | 101          |
|4  |   105       | 103          |
----------------------------------
```

result should be 1 -> 101 ->105 or 3->105->101

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I want these(result should be 1 -> 101 ->105 or 3->105->101) result from above table .

Comment: Why do you need the result like that? `[101, 105]` has the same information.

Comment: I want these result because I want get list  who are following each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the row where follower and following match you could use a self join

```
select t1.* from my_table as t1
inner  join my_table as t2 
where t1.follower_id = t2.following_id
and  t1.following_id = t2.follower_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `least` and `greatest` to do this.

```
select * from t
where (least(follower_id,following_id),greatest(follower_id,following_id))
in (select least(follower_id,following_id),greatest(follower_id,following_id)
    from t
    group by least(follower_id,following_id),greatest(follower_id,following_id)
    having count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this Query will help you....

```
SELECT *
FROM Yourtable A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Yourtable B WHERE B.follower = A.following)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Yourtable C WHERE C.following = A.follower)
```